# Android touch listeners?

Tags: android, onclick, actionlistener, onlongclicklistener

I need to nest s few touch listeners. For example I have a ViewGroup that will have the following listeners: onItemClick, onLongItemClick and onTouch.EV == move.

The items inside the view group will have an onClick as well.

In my tests both sets of listeners work independently, but not interdependently. Is there any way I can interlink the listener groups?

Thanks, 
~Aedon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i´m not sure, but maybe you can dispatch the touch event from the root view to its child view (starting with the activity)

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (ChildView.dispatchTouchEvent(event))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

after the user clicked the button, dispatch the touch event back to the root view.

Comment: Ah, fantastic I'll try it here in a moment, thank you greatly!

Answer (score 2):

All events are propagated from root to child views. If a view does not want to handle a event it passes it to its child views. If a view consumes a event such a click on a ViewGroup, you can either let it trickle down or block it. Usually returning false from event callback indicates the event was not handled, and returning true indicates event was handled and will not be given to any other views.

Say you have a button in a ViewGroup. If you press the button, the ViewGroup will receive the event first, it can chose to not to pass the event to its children, in which case the button will not respond to the click.

Comment: Right; that's what I read in the developers article. But that doesn't really do what I need. It needs to work backwards, if it's possible. I need to know that the user is clicking the button before I allow the parent ViewGroup to execute it's listeners.

Comment: You simply cant. The root view always gets the events first. Trust me dont spend your time on this.

Comment: I see, and accept that the root view will always receive the first listener. But I think ther is a work around that I am unaware of and can not achieve. If you think about a widget on a launcher screen it has a few basic touch options: onClick and onLongClick. But if you were to look at specific widgets, such as the reddit widget or a media widget, they also contain buttons in the widget as well. The button press takes priority for the widget but is still capable of being click and/or dragged about the screen. This is what I hope to achieve.

Comment: That does mean the child views are getting the events first. read this http://groups.google.com/group/android-framework/browse_thread/thread/2cdd4269dfb2772e You need to figure out which events to intercept and which ones to process

Comment: I'm sorry I have read that thread three times now and I'm still unsure how to implement it...